# How can i use your plugin with flippingbook

Tags: wordpress

Hy!
I would like to use your plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/) to appear my flippingbook publication in lightbox like on this page: http://flippingbook.com/presentation-examples/
How can I set the plugin to show in the window.
My homepage is wordpress, and I use 'Avada' theme from themeforest. I can't show you my page bacause it's in Maintenance Mode at present.
Can you send me a html code what I have to write to work on my page correct?
Thanks,
Panka

Answer (score 0):

I tried the fancybox plugin for wordpress before and had trouble with using it. I found [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-lightbox/) plug
Once activated you just add `rel="lightbox"` to a link of the image. E.g.

```
<a  href="IMAGELINK" rel="lightbox"><img src="IMGLINK"></a>
```